# Question on $e^y=e^{{e}^{x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$e^y=e^{{e}^{x}}$

Then which of the value of y is correct, $y=e^x$ or $y=ex$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$y=e^x$ is correct.

Because $e^{f(x)}=e^{g(x)}$ if and only if $f(x)=g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the natural logarithm of both sides cancels out the base exponent $e$:
$$
e^y = e^{e^{x}} \\
\ln( e^y ) = \ln( e^{e^{x}} ) \\
y = e^x
$$

Comment: That mean, one has to be careful while writing $e^y=e^{e^x}$ and $e^y=e^{ex}$ as they are two separate thing.

Answer (score 1):

If $e^y = e^{e^x}$, then we may take the natural logarithm of both sides: $\ln(e^y) = \ln(e^{e^x})$.  What is the natural logarithm of $e^z$ for any $z\in\mathbb{R}$?  It's the exponent, $z$.

So for the problem at hand, we have $\ln(e^y) = \ln(e^{e^x}) \implies y = e^x$.

Comment: But here $e^{e^x}$ can also be $e^{ex}$. In that case $y=e^x$ and $y=e^{ex}$

Comment: Hi Rajesh, I think your confusion comes from the notation.  When we write $a^{b^c}$ for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, what this really means is to evaluate either $(a^b)^c$ or $a^{(b^c)}$ (order doesn't matter).  However, $e^{e^x}$ is NOT the same thing as $e^{ex}$.  These are two different expressions.